Get the Item value from the foreach activity value if the item value/Folder_Name contains .csv child items
I want to use foreach activity and want to use the item value passed to each foreach.
First it will use the item value to get the metadata of the folder from the parameterized adls location. If the Adls location contain childitems, i want to use append variable to append the item value. And use the append variable value for further processing


Using metadata activity to check child items
If present append the item value from the for each to append in the append variable.

You can use Filter activity and append variable activity to achieve your requirement.
First create an array type variable in the pipeline variables section and don't give any values in the default section.
In the For-each activity, select the Sequential if you want to preserve the same order of the original folders array. Otherwise, you can go ahead with Parallel execution of the for-each activity.
Inside For-each, after Get meta data activity2, check whether this child items array contains .csv files and get a filtered child items array.
Give the below expressions in the filer activity.
Items - @activity('Get Metadata2').output.childItems

Condition - @contains(item().name,'.csv')


If you want to get folder names which contains atleast one .csv file, check the length of this array is o or not in the if activity condition. If you want the folder names where all the child items should be .csv files, then check whether the length of Get meta data activity 2 child items array and length of filtered array equals or not.
Condition for the folders which contains atleast one .csv file.
@greater(length(activity('Filter1').output.value),0)


Inside, True activities of if activity, take append variable activity from the menu. Take the array variable that was created earlier in the pipeline variable section.

The above expression @item() will create array of objects like Get meta data activity child items. If you want to create an array of only folder names like ["folder1","folder2"], give the expression @item().name.
You cannot see the append variable result during the pipeline run but you can access this variable after the for-each activity. To check the variable result, create another set variable activity of array type after the For-each activity and assign this variable folders_list to that.

Now, debug the pipeline it will show the required folder names as an array of objects.

My pipeline JSON for your reference:
{
    "name": "6th_pipeline",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Get Metadata1",
                "type": "GetMetadata",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "fieldList": [
                        "childItems"
                    ],
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                        "recursive": true,
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Get Metadata1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Get Metadata2",
                            "type": "GetMetadata",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "dataset": {
                                    "referenceName": "folder_files",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "folder_name": {
                                            "value": "@item().name",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "fieldList": [
                                    "childItems"
                                ],
                                "storeSettings": {
                                    "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                    "recursive": true,
                                    "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                },
                                "formatSettings": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "If Condition1",
                            "type": "IfCondition",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Filter1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "expression": {
                                    "value": "@greater(length(activity('Filter1').output.value),0)",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                },
                                "ifTrueActivities": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "Append variable1",
                                        "type": "AppendVariable",
                                        "dependsOn": [],
                                        "userProperties": [],
                                        "typeProperties": {
                                            "variableName": "folders_list",
                                            "value": {
                                                "value": "@item()",
                                                "type": "Expression"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Filter1",
                            "type": "Filter",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Get Metadata2",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "items": {
                                    "value": "@activity('Get Metadata2').output.childItems",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                },
                                "condition": {
                                    "value": "@contains(item().name,'.csv')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "just res show",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "ForEach1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "res_show",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@variables('folders_list')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "folders_list": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "res_show": {
                "type": "Array"
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "lastPublishTime": "2024-08-06T12:47:17Z"
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}

